# is it possible to make a custom input format with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i need to know if it's possible, with tkinter, to make an input in a messagebox to take the date with a format like this: __/ __/ ____
If it isn't possible is there a fast method to check if the date was put correctly?

I tried to analyse the string to check if the data was ok but it takes so much lines and time because there are many possibilities!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is that really all you're asking? There's nothing built-in, but it has everything you need to make it yourself.

Comment: ok thanks but i need to know how

Comment: @Marco: Read about [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) this function allows to check with on `try: ... except:` block.